# Map<sObject, List<sObject>> values not showing on VF page in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

this is controller

```java
public class AccountContactController {
    public Map<Account, List<Contact>> accountContactMap { get; set; }
    
    public AccountContactController() {
        accountContactMap = new Map<Account, List<Contact>>();
        
        Account acct1 = new Account(Name='Acme Corporation');
        Contact contact1 = new Contact(FirstName='John', LastName='Doe', Email='johndoe@acme.com', AccountId=acct1.Id);
        Contact contact2 = new Contact(FirstName='Jane', LastName='Doe', Email='janedoe@acme.com', AccountId=acct1.Id);
        List<Contact> contacts1 = new List<Contact>{contact1, contact2};
        accountContactMap.put(acct1, contacts1);
        
        Account acct2 = new Account(Name='XYZ Inc.');
        Contact contact3 = new Contact(FirstName='Bob', LastName='Smith', Email='bobsmith@xyz.com', AccountId=acct2.Id);
        List<Contact> contacts2 = new List<Contact>{contact3};
        accountContactMap.put(acct2, contacts2);
    }
}
```

and this is VF

```html
    <apex:page controller="AccountContactController">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account Name</th>
                <th>Contact Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!accountContactMap}" var="acct">
                <apex:repeat value="{!accountContactMap[acct]}" var="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!acct.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.FirstName} {!contact.LastName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.Email}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Values from accountContactMap is not displaying

Map output

```
{
  Account:{Name=Acme Corporation, Id=001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}=(Contact:{AccountId=001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Email=johndoe@acme.com, FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Id=003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX},Contact:{AccountId=001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Email=janedoe@acme.com, FirstName=Jane, LastName=Doe, Id=003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}), 
  Account:{Name=XYZ Inc., Id=001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}=(Contact:{AccountId=001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Email=bobsmith@xyz.com, FirstName=Bob, LastName=Smith, Id=003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX})
}
```

Comment: i tried your same code but when i preview the VF page i am able to see the VF page with correct values of map, do you see any error ?